# React-native and react dependency conflicts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

Currently I'm using React Native 0.42.0 with React 15.4.2, and there is a bugfix: `Fix crash if native code tries to update the size of a modal view after JS has removed it` in the 0.44.0 which is the latest release of the React Native. I wanted to update for the latest version but it's require 16.0.0-alpha.6 React version. There is problems, because the other npm packages don't support the alpha version of the React and they require the 15.x.x version.

What is the proper solution for this problem?

There is my related part of the package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.16.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "querystring": "^0.2.0",
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.6",
    "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.4.2",
    "react-native": "0.44.0",
    "react-native-cookies": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^0.10.2",
    "react-native-lazyload": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-router-flux": "^3.38.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.4",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.3",
    "redux": "^3.6.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this can be taken as a response but in my case having the same problem i only updated into the latest version possible without depending on the alpha version of react (0.42), and we'll need to wait until the next React.js versions comes out.

The official explain that i heard was that react-native take some React Fiber considerations that are not included on React.js for now